Smallest gaussian summation to fit a number?
I am not a mathematician so my vocabulary may be seen as a misfit, but there we go:
Given a number, what is the fastest way to find the smallest Gaussian summation this number fits in ?
For example, the smallest summation for the number 8 is 1+2+3+4=10.
Those results happen to be binomial coefficients (10,15,21,28..).
Obviously one can try multiple calculations, but my question is: is there a direct way to find it (or greatly narrow down the pool of solution)?

As one answer has pointed out, the usual term for this is triangular number.

The $n^\text{th}$ triangular number is given by:
$$T_n=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}.$$
This gives the sequence: $\{1,3,6,10,15,21,\dots\}$.

EXAMPLE:
Put $T_n=8$, we get $8=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$.
By rearranging, we get $16=n^2+n \implies n^2+n-16=0$
Solving for $n$, we have
$$n=\frac{-1\color{red}+\sqrt{1^2-4 \cdot 1 \cdot(-16)}}{2}\space\space\space\space\space \text{[we take }{\color{red}+}\text{ sign because }n \text{ is positive]}.$$
Simplifying, we get $n=3.53\dots$.
Round it up because we need to find the number that $ \color{red}{\textbf{fits in}}$. So now we say $n=4$.
Calculate the $4^\text{th}$ triangular number, using the formula above, we get
$$T_4=\frac{4(4+1)}{2}=10$$

After rearranging, one can find the following formula:
$$S=\frac{1}{2}\left \lceil \frac{-1+\sqrt{1+8n}}{2} \right \rceil\bigg(1+\left \lceil \frac{-1+\sqrt{1+8n}}{2} \right \rceil\bigg)$$
where $S$ is the smallest triangular number that fits $n$, and $\left \lceil \cdot\right \rceil$ is the least integer function (ceiling function).

If the number is $n$, then the smallest Gaussian summation is equal to,
$$ \frac{1}{2}\left( \sqrt{8n+1} - 1 \right) $$
For example, if $n=8$, then that calculation gives $3.53$, since this number is not a positive integer you just round it up to a positive integer, getting that $1+2+3+4$ now exceeds the desired number $8$.
